# Setting value of item in a List given next item with a certain value

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of SalesOrders, both Inactive and Active. I want to loop through this entire list and set the length of time each SalesOrder was Active for. (The list is already ordered by StartTime)

My loop is as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < salesOrders.size(); i++) {
    if(salesOrders.get(i).getStatus() == RecordStatus.ACTIVE) {
        ELDDutyLog activeSalesOrder = salesOrders.get(i);

        for(int j = i + 1; j < salesOrders.size(); j++) {
            if(salesOrders.get(j).getStatus() == RecordStatus.ACTIVE) {
                ELDDutyLog nextActiveSalesOrder = salesOrders.get(j);

                salesOrders.get(i).setActiveDurationMinutes(
                    Minutes.minutesBetween(
                        activeSalesOrder.getStartTime(),
                        nextActiveSalesOrder.getStartTime()
                    ).getMinutes()
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
return salesOrders;
```

While this approach works, I feel there must be a better way of doing this, possibly by using Java 8? Can anyone provide me with any direction around this?

Comment: My bad, that was a typo

Comment: Just as @Eran said are `RecordStatus` and `ELDRecordStatus` the same?, cos if they are not the second `if` statement will never be executed and so is unnecessary.

Comment: How do you know that `salesOrders.get(i)` and `salesOrders.get(j)` represent the same `SalesOrder`? The logic is not clear.

Comment: Questions about working code do not belong on Stack Overflow. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate. There are *way* too many questions which can be boiled down to "please convert this to Java 8 Streams".

Comment: If the code works and needs optimisation, you may be better off going to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to loop the entire list again, each time skipping the inactive sales orders. Instead, you can filter the active sales orders once, then you always know that the next active sales order is the next order in the filtered list.

Something like this (not tested):

```
List<ELDDutyLog> activeSalesOrders = salesOrders.stream()
        .filter(so -> so.getStatus() == RecordStatus.ACTIVE)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i = 0; i < activeSalesOrders.size() - 1; i++) {
    activeSalesOrders.get(i).setActiveDurationMinutes(
                    Minutes.minutesBetween(
                        activeSalesOrders.get(i).getStartTime(),
                        activeSalesOrders.get(i+1).getStartTime()
                    ).getMinutes()
                );
}
```

Comment: I like this; I can't understand the fuss to do everything in a "single line"... +1

Comment: @Eugene generally I agree with you, that a single line should not be the goal unto itself. In this case though the fuss is in how many times you need to iterate each item in the list. In the OP example, each item is iterated numerous times. In this example each item is iterated once and the active items are iterated a second time. With Java 8 streams, it is often possible to iterate the each item only once. On a larger collection, this may may provide a performance improvement. Some people also prefer the expressiveness of the fluent API to better describe the intention of their code.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I only meant it as a "general" comment as such there is nothing that I could not agree with in your statement

Comment: In the OP’s code, the inner loop starts at the current position of the outer loop and does a `break` at the first match, so each item is only iterated two times rather than “numerous times”. It’s still more than in your code as your code doesn’t need to deal with non-`ACTIVE` items in the second loop. But there’s even a [single iteration solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208171/2711488) possible…

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand correctly.  Try (not tested):

```
salesOrders.stream()
  .filter(salesOrder -> salesOrder.getStatus() == RecordStatus.ACTIVE)
  .reduce((current, next) -> {
    current.setActiveDurationMinutes(
      Minutes.minutesBetween(
        current.getStartTime(),
        next.getStartTime()
      ).getMinutes()
    );
    return next;
  });
```

To be honest... it's a bit of a weird use for `reduce`, but I think it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to nest two loops; the `nextActiveSalesOrder` you have searched for to calculate the argument for the `setActiveDurationMinutes` call, is the same object that will become the `activeSalesOrder` you are searching for in the next iterations of the outer loop. Besides that, you are unnecessarily calling `salesOrders.get(i)` in the inner operation despite you already have that value stored in `activeSalesOrder`.

```
ELDDutyLog activeSalesOrder = null;
for(ELDDutyLog nextActiveSalesOrder: salesOrders) {
    if(nextActiveSalesOrder.getStatus() != RecordStatus.ACTIVE) continue;
    if(activeSalesOrder != null)
        activeSalesOrder.setActiveDurationMinutes(
            Minutes.minutesBetween(
                activeSalesOrder.getStartTime(),
                nextActiveSalesOrder.getStartTime()
            ).getMinutes()
        );
    activeSalesOrder = nextActiveSalesOrder;
}
```

Besides that… what kind of API requires you to write something like `Minutes.minutesBetween(a, b).getMinutes()`? How many times can an API need to be told that you want *minutes*?
Compare to `java.time`:

1. `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(a, b)` (returns a `long` already) or
2. `a.until(b, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` (dito, still no redundancy)